# jQuery - replacing found character with other one

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hello everyone I've got short problem, i wrote test code with string replacement in jquery. It works, but i need to modyfy it to find a character x in given string what is working but it doesnt want to swap with Y letter when i change var res = value.replace(value, "Y"); to var res = myX.replace(myX, "Y"); i.e if i put 'max' string into text box input i want to replace only x with letter Y in this case. Anyone know how to change it?
Thanks for your attention and help :)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        pls provide here your function
        <input type="button" value="Replace" id="lineFunctionClick"/>
        <input type="text" id="myInput">
    </div>

    <script>    
    $("#lineFunctionClick").on("click", function () {
        var value = $("#myInput").val();
        var myX = value.indexOf('x');
        if (myX >= 0)
        {
            var res = value.replace(value, "Y");
            alert("changed" + " " + value + " " + "to" + " " + res);
        } else
        {
            alert("value doesnt exist");
        }
    });

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Becuase you are trying to replace the index position and not 'x'. myX  contains the position of the search string. Below change will fix the issue.

Replace

```
var res = value.replace(value, "Y");
```

with

```
var res = value.replace('x', "Y");
```

Comment: I though i can do sth like that var res = value.replace(myX, "Y");
but it doesnt work your conclusion is working :) thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regex to do that:

```js
(function(){
  var regex = /x/gi;
  var str1 = "max";
  var str2 = "Xmas";
  var str3 = "XXXxxxxxXxxx";
  
  console.log(str1.replace(regex, 'y'));
  console.log(str2.replace(regex, 'y'));
  console.log(str3.replace(regex, 'y'));
})()
```